# Class [JeeNamespaceHandler] for namespace [../schema/jee] does not implement the [NamespaceHandler] interface

Tags: spring-mvc, resources

> Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [`D:\Jboss\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\conf\inv-config\app-config\persistence-config.spring.xml`]; nested exception is `org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException`: Class [`org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler`] for namespace [`http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee`] does not implement the [`org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler`] interface

I am using spring 3.0.5 on jboss 4.2.2 .

The `persistence-config.spring.xml` file is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<!-- JNDI Environment Properties -->
<bean id="jndiEnvProps" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">
                <![CDATA[org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]]>
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://127.0.0.1:1099</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Data Source Definition -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="zaraINVDS" environment-ref="jndiEnvProps" />

<!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:/zaraINVEMF" proxy-interface="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

<!-- JTA Transaction Manager -->
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

<!-- Annotation Driven Transaction Management -->
<tx:annotation-driven order="5"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you have two copies of Spring on your classpath. The classloader is getting conflicts between them.  Track them down, and remove one of them.